# is it possible to run .R file in windows if R software is not installed in computer

Tags: r

I want to run an R script on a computer which doesn't have the R software installed on it. Is it possible to do this in any way?

Comment: No it is not possible. R code needs to be interpreted by an R interpreter, it does not generate executable binaries.

Comment: You could use Docker to create a distributable.

Comment: I don't know if it is still possible, but in the past I have run R off a thumb drive.

Answer (score 5):

If you have internet and a browser on the machine without R go to:

http://r-fiddle.org

or

http://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/Rweb/

and paste the source of the R file into it.

Alternately, note that R is free and has an automated installer so it's pretty easy to install R on a new machine.  Google for

> download R windows

Download it.  Run the downloaded executable and press enter for each question.